# Как сделать вызов абоненту?

Tags: javascript, phonegap

В PhoneGap есть метод позволяющий вернуть контакт из телефонной книги, а есть ли способ позволяющий сделать вызов этому абоненту мощностями PhoneGap'a или HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, если это отдаленно желаемый результат, но если в тег ссылки внутри атрибута `href` поместить url со схемой `tel:` перед номером, то по нажатии пользователю будет предложено сделать вызов на этот номер.

пример

```
<a href='tel:+712345678'>12345678</a>
```